# How to move/drag node from one group to another?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am new in go.js and I have a problem. I have two groups and both have two elements. I want to move element from one group to another. I believe it should be very simple, but I cannot find solution. Any ideas?

Below I attached minimal version of two groups with two elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/2.0.5/go.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script>
     function init() {
         var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
          myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
          var nodeDataArray = [
                   { key: "Group 1", isGroup: true },
        { key: "A", group: "Group 1" },
        { key: "B", group: "Group 1" },
        { key: "Group 2", isGroup: true },
        { key: "C", group: "Group 2" },
                    { key: "D", group: "Group 2" }
          ];
          
          myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray);
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:300px; height:300px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, see this sample: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/regrouping.html.

If you look at the code, you will see that you need to set **mouseDrop** on the Group template to a function that adds the dropped nodes to be members of the group.  See how the `finishDrop` function is defined in that sample.

It also helps to set **computesBoundsAfterDrag** to true and **handlesDragDropForMembers** to true.

Optionally, it is nice to set **mouseDragEnter** and **mouseDragLeave** to provide visual feedback during the drag before the drop.